# Laravel $posts->comments() isn't working here

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Here is the code from my Models:

`models/Book.php`

> class Book extends \Eloquent {
>
> ```
> function posts() {
>     return $this->hasMany('Post');
> }
>
> function user() {
>     return $this->belongsTo('User');
> }
>
> public function cover()
> {
>     return $this->morphMany('Image', 'imageable');
> }
>
> public function delete()
> {
>    $this->posts()->comments()->delete();
>
>     $this->posts()->delete();
>
>     $this->cover()->delete();
>     // delete the model
>     return parent::delete();
> }
> ```
>
> }

`models/Post.php`

> Class Post extends Eloquent {
>
> ```
> function book() {
>     return $this->belongsTo('Book');
> }
>
> function comments() {
>     return $this->hasMany('Comment');
> }
>
> function user() {
>     return $this->belongsTo('User');
> }
>
> public function delete()
> {
>     $this->comments()->delete();
>     // delete the model
>     return parent::delete();
> }
> ```
>
> }

`models/Comment.php`

> Class Comment extends Eloquent {
>
> ```
> function post() {
>     return $this->belongsTo('Post');
> }
>
> function user() {
>     return $this->belongsTo('User');
> }
> ```
>
> }

but in my `UserController.php` I cannot access my comment. I tried with these code:

> ```
> public function show($id)
> {
>         $user = User::find($id);
>
>         $posts = Post::whereUserId($user->id)
>                   ->orderBy('created_at','deac')->get();
>
>         $comments = $posts->comments();
>         dd($comments);
> }
> ```

This always says:
[image]

How to access my comments under the posts? also I don't think `$this->posts()->comments()->delete();` isn't working.

Comment: are you trying to only get a specific users Comments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a relation in your `User` model like this:

```
// User model
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Book');
}
```

Then in your `controller`:

```
public function show($id)
{
    // User->hasMany:books->hasMany:posts->hasMany:Comments
    $user = User::with('books.posts.comments')->find($id);
    return View::make('viewName')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Then in your `view`:

```
{{ $user->nameMaybe }}
{{ $user->emailMaybe }}
@foreach($user->books as $book)
    {{ $book->title }}
    {{ $book->author }}
    @foreach($book->posts as $post)
        {{ $post->slugMaybe }}
        {{ $post->postTitleMaybe }}
        @foreach($post->comments as $comment)
            {{ $comment->commenttextMaybe }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

The structure of the returned `User` model would be something like this (According to your relation):

```
Model: User (object)
           ->name (Property of User Model)
           ->email (Property of User Model) and more properties
           -> books (property of User Model, collection of Book Models
              -> [0] Book (has properties)
              -> [1] Book (has properties
                 -> posts (property of [1]Book, collection of Post Models
                 -> [0] Post (has properties)
                 -> [1] Post (has properties
                    -> comments (property of [1]Post, collection of Comment Models
                    -> [0] Comment (has properties)
                    -> [1] Comment (has properties
```

Comment: on my `User` model:
`public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Book');
}`

already exists, let me try with the controller.

Comment: `return View::make('viewName')->with('book', $book);` says:
Undefined variable: book

Comment: So, you have `books` in `user` model ?

Comment: Then you don't need to add that function as I said at first.

Comment: Oops! My mistake, it had to be `with('user', $user)` not `with('book', $book)` :-)

Comment: how to use `orderBy('created_at','desc')` with `$user = User::with('books.posts.comments')->find($id);` ? I want the `posts` and the `comments` get ordered

Comment: Try this `$user = User::with('books.posts' => function($postsQuery){
  $postsQuery::with('comments' => function($commentsQuery){
   $commentsQuery->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
  })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
 })->find($id);`.